# cannot change volume of audio with useRef

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am keep getting `The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access` error while wanting to change the volume of the `htmlaudioelement`

any idea on how to fix this ?

my code

```
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState<number>(50)
  const musicPlayers:HTMLAudioElement | undefined(
    typeof Audio !== "undefined"
      ? new Audio("")
      : undefined
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    musicPlayers.current?.volume = volume
  }, [volume]);

     <input
      type="range"
      className="w-full"
      value={volume}
      onChange={(e) => setVolume(e.target.value)}
    />
```

thanks

Comment: Did you forget to add `<input ref={musicPlayers} .../>`? Also, I think it should be `musicPlayers.current.value`.

Comment: @kausko Hi, even if I make it a simple const musicplayer instead of a ref the errors is still there. the current.value is an audio element which has volume in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because you're attempting to assign a value to a property of an object that might be `null` or `undefined`.

Example:

```
musicPlayers.current?.volume = volume;
```

You can fix this by checking beforehand if the object exists.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!!musicPlayers.current) {
    musicPlayers.current.volume = volume;
  }
}, [musicPlayers, volume])
```

Comment: Hi, that indeed works, but the "?" does check that it is not undefined no ? what is the "!!" ? because if(musicplayer.current) also works

Comment: The `?` does check undefined but TypeScript doesn't like using that when you're attempting to assign to a property of a possible `null` or `undefined` object. If you're trying to grab the value, you can safely use optional chaining but not when assigning. The `!!` converts the condition to a boolean value. Example: `1` is truthy but `!!1` is truthy and is `true` --`1 === true` is false while `!!1 === true` will be true